# HTML - Merge two head tags into one

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-2

I am trying to merge two html heads by php include()-ing a php file (which contain the header for reusability) into another. The code works but it results into this:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">        
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery191.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jqueryui1103.js" ></script>

</head><html>
<head>
    <title>Add Employee Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/addform.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/talentform.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/form_submission.js" ></script>
</head>
```

Which is I think against the standards. Is there a way of merging those two heads into one without violating the standards? By the way, I am using CodeIgniter 2 Framework, if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Why not have the php files only have what's within the `<head>` and then wrap it around? Example: echo "<head>"; include(1); include(2); echo "</head>";?

Comment: Where is your code that has gotten you this far?

Comment: @DaveChen Thanks for the idea! I removed the head tags of the first file and then transferred the include inside the head tag of the second file. Thanks everyone! I realized this is a very noob question. Sorry for my noobness.